# Convexification of $\frac{a}{12}\,(x^4-2\,x^2)+b\,x$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, convex-analysis, convex-hulls, quartics

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$
$$f(x)=\frac{a}{12}\,(x^4-2\,x^2)+b\,x\,$$
with parameters $a,b>0\,$. $f$ is concave on the interval $\left[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right]$ and convex outside.

I am interested in the *convex* function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$  which is as close as possible to $f$. Precisely, I want to minimise the oscilation
$$\textrm{osc}(f-g) := \sup_{x\in\mathbb R}(f(x)-g(x)) - \inf_{x\in\mathbb R}(f(x)-g(x)) \;.$$

Is it possible to compute $g$ (or a good approximation of it)? Can we get a good estimate of $\textrm{osc}(f-g)$ as a function of the parameters $a,b$? Can we estimate $\textrm{osc}(f-g)$ when $b$ is large?

It may be useful to distinguish the following two cases.

- If $3^5\,b^2<4\,a^2$, $f$ should have two minimum points $m_1,m_2$ such that $m_1<-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}<m_2$. In this case intuitively I would build $g$ drawing a line that connects $(m_1+\delta_1,f(m_1+\delta_1))$ and $(m_2+\delta_2,f(m_2+\delta_2))$ for suitable $\delta_1,\delta_2>0$. Which $\delta_1,\delta_2$?

[image]

- If $3^5\,b^2>4\,a^2$, $f$ should have only one minimum point $m<-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. In this case I have less intuition about what to do...

[image]

Comment: What does it mean to minimize $\operatorname{osc}(f, g)$? Does it mean to minimize its integral across the entire domain $\mathbb{R}$? Or something else?

Comment: @BrianTung $osc(f-g)$ is just a constant defined as the $sup$ minus the $inf$ of the function $f(x)-g(x)$ over $x\in\mathbb R$. I wrote the definition more explicitly.

Comment: Intuitively, I would anticipate that the minimizer is the [convex envelope](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328907/a-question-regarding-the-convex-envelope-of-a-function) of the original function. See for instance the image [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Convex-envelope-of-univariate-function_fig1_226086974).

Comment: @Semiclassical is there a method to compute it? I am mainly interested in estimating $\textrm{osc}(f-g)$ when the parameter $b$ is large

Comment: The value of $b$ shouldn't make a difference to the optimal oscillation. If you replace $g(x) $ with $g(x) - bx$ you get another arbitrary convex function. This makes the problem equivalent to the $b = 0$ problem.

Comment: @BenMartin I have to think for a moment about what you are saying. If $b=0$ I think the problem is easy because the two minima are equal ($f(m_1)=f(m_2)$) and I can draw a horizontal line connecting $(m_1,f(m_1))$ and $(m_2,f(m_2))$ to convexify the function. So when $b=0$ it should be $\textrm{osc}(f-g)=\frac{a}{12}$.

Comment: Finding the convex envelope of the curve amounts to finding the convex hull of the area above said curve. There's a number of [convex hull algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms), but typically these are for point sets not curves. One exception to this is Lucet's LLT algorithm (original paper [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1019191114493), SciLab implementation [here](https://cmps-people.ok.ubc.ca/ylucet/CCA/man/lft_llt.htm).)

Comment: @BenMartin I think you are right, the minimum of $\textrm{osc(f-g)}$ over convex functions $g$ does not depend on the parameter $b$. Therefore it suffices to compute it for $b=0$. If you want to write a complete answer, I'll vote it

Comment: @Semiclassical If I understand correctly, defining the Legendre transform $f^*(y)=\sup_x(xy-f(x))$ we get that $f^**$ is the convex envelope of $f$ (for any continuous function $f$). So this is the theoretical answer to my question. Then one should figure out how to compute the Legendre transform

Comment: Yes: the double Legendre transform returns the convex envelope. For more discussion see the paper [here](https://www.ise.ncsu.edu/fuzzy-neural/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2019/01/or706-LF-transform-1.pdf).

Comment: Also, one way to make this particular problem easier to analyze is to write the function of interest as $f(x)=\frac{a}{12}(x^2-1)^2+b x-\frac{a}{12}$. Then the convex envelope in the middle is obtained by finding a linear function $f_c(x)$ which is tangent to the curve at two points, i.e., $f(x)-f_c(x)$ has two double roots. Is there an obvious choice for $f_c(x)$?

Comment: @Semiclassical very nice, it suffices to take $f_c(x)=b x - \frac{a}{12}$ and this give the convex envelope. So again, as pointed out by BenMartin, the minimal oscilation does not depend on $b$

Comment: @tituf Please consider answering your own question when you can find some time.